# Is this a good db architecture and if not what can i change about it

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, many-to-many, database-normalization

[image: Database structure]

I found this in an old post and i'm thinking of using it for a project, but i don't know if i should change it or leave it, here's what i want to change:

- remove **product options** and add *product id* and *option group id* to **options**
- remove **order details** and have it's info in **orders**

is what i'm doing bad? also if you could be kind to tell me some of the best practices for something like this i would greatly appreciate it.

thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello salah1337, welcome to Stack Overflow. Ths question does lack details. We can't answer your question unless you give many more details on what you are trying to implement, and where you are currently stucked.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, basically i don't know if the tables _productoptions_ and _orderdetails_ really have a purpose, does structuring the db this way help with something later on? or can i just combine the _options_ with _productoptions_ , and _orderdetails_ with _details_

Comment: if you see order and order details table there is one to many relationship, similarly product options table is there for normalising the many to many relation between product and option, this entity relation diagram has normalised table representation so better do not change it.

Comment: @AnshulSharma For database normalization please use [tag:database-normalization] not [tag:normalization]. PS Replacing values by other values that are somehow more id-ish is not normalization. However combining order & orderdetails here can reasonably be called denormalization.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).  Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @philipxy I mean to say, when we have *One To May*, *Many To Many* these relationships we do normalization and this diagram is taking care of it.

Comment: @AnshulSharma Normalization does not have anything in particular to do with dealing with 1:M & M:M, they exist before & after it & they are always around whether one is normalizing or not, it is about certain bad FDs & JDs, not 1:M & M:M. I just told you one of the transformations here has nothing to do with nromalization while the other could be thought of as undoing a normalization one might have done to get here or that one would want to do to undo what is being suggested here. Anyway, I'm done here.

Comment: To judge a schema, we need to see the `SELECTs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tables are there for a good reason.

`productoptions` is a mapping table between `options`  and `products`: this is a many-to-many relationship, where a given product may have multiple options, and an option may be used by  multiple products. If you remove this table, you end up redondantly adding the `optionName` to each and every row in `productoptions` that relate to the same option, which is inefficient, and might break data integrity (how do you ensure that a given option always has the same name?).

As for `order_details`: this is a many to one relationship towards `orders`. An order may have mutliple details line, each referring to a different product. Removing this table means losing this possibility.